# Cannot ssh into a host using hostname.local

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, hostname

When trying to ssh from terminal into my raspberry pi using: `ssh pi@hostname.local` the connection just hangs forever.

When I ping pi@hostname.local, I get `ping: cannot resolve pi@hostname.local: Unknown host`

I can ping and ssh with the ip address just fine using: `ssh pi@192.168.xxx.xxx`

Not sure if I need to configure my laptop network settings (macOS) or the raspberry pi settings (Debian) to be able to connect via hostname.

Comment: where are you `ssh`ing from ? from pi to pi ? (that's should be OK) from mac to pi ? you should use pi's hostname or IP. can you `ssh pi@192.168.xxx.xxx` ?

Comment: `ping` should be used with an IP address or a resolvable name.  Inserting a username `pi@hostname.local` would not be expected to work.

Comment: possibly related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local  (mDNS ...)

Comment: @Archemar ssh-ing from Mac to pi. `ssh pi@192.168.xxx.xxx` does work, so does `ssh 192.168.xxx.xxx`.

Comment: @user4556274 It's just that `ssh pi@hostname.local` does work, but only sometimes.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. It is a legit question and @bakunin gave a legit explanation and solution below.

Comment: are you using more than one pi, each of them having `hostname`  as hostname ?

Comment: "Not sure why this was downvoted."  Nor am I, but the answer you got certainly should be - the answer you've accepted is incorrect. RPi uses a zero-configuration networking (a multicast DNS) with the `avahi` package. You can't reach it from hosts that don't also use multicast DNS (mDNS). macOS has this, and if it's in the same subnet as your RPi, my guess is that it just hasn't had time to resolve it yet.

Comment: @Seamus but that solution worked, so I accepted it. If you can articulate a better solution, I’ll accept yours.

Comment: @Archemar only one pi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you give a host a hostname, only this host knows about it. Any other host doesn't know the hostname (and the IP address it corresponds to) at all. A little different are name services (like DNS, NIS, ...), which "distribute" this knowledge across a network. But for our purposes only the host himself knows its hostname.

Having said this: you want to connect from a system (let us call it "yourpc") to another system ("pi"). For this to work "yourpc" has to know which IP address corresponds to this name "pi". In absence of any name service there is one way to enlighten "yourpc", which is: enter the hostname and its corresponding IP address to the file `/etc/hosts`. In fact this is the specific purpose of this file.

A typical `/etc/hosts` file looks like this:

```
# Place comments after octothorpe signs, like in shell scripts
10.1.1.1       host1
10.1.1.2       host2
10.1.1.3       host3      # an inline comment is also possible
# you can also specify "aliases" - multiple names under which the host is also known
10.1.1.4       host4  myraspberrypi
...
```

As an afterthought and thanks to a suggestion of @Archemar:

User names are irrelevant on the IP level. At this level we deal only with hosts (or, rather, their interfaces), networks and similar entities. Users or their names never enter this picture at this level.

Using the above example hosts-file the following are all equal:

```
ssh someuser@10.1.1.4
ssh someuser@host4
ssh someuser@myraspberrypi
```